# Can't add Deployment Manager in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

When we attempt to add a Deployment Manager in CRM 2013 it accepts the AD user account and pops a action dialogue with a progress bar titled "Adding".  After waiting 15 minutes the progress bar continues to spin.  No errors and nothing in the event logs of SQL Server or the CRM server.  When I attempt the same action in my local dev VM I can add a newly created test AD User account with no permissions or groups to the Deployment Managers with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that one of colleagues has similar issues but unfortunately I don't remember what was the reason for error. What I can suggest is [workaround](http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2013/01/add-new-deployment-administrator.html).